# Executing a jquery page fader using a Timer with Execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a request for assistance concerning what is best described as a “Time Triggered Event”, (a timer?). I'm working on a basic simple 3 page site using a jQuery page fade code to fade from Pg1 to Pg2 to Pg3 (shown below).

The jQuery code uses a “click on link” to execute the fade between pages. Works Great! I would like to eliminate this “click on link” and replace it with a “Timer”. Rather than a Manual Click to execute the page fade, a timer will pause for a set period of time, then execute the jquery page fade code to the next page.

Here is the jQuery page fade code I'm using:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Click on the link to see the fade effect.</p>
        <a href="#pagetwo" data-transition="fade">Fade to Page Two</a>
      </div>

      <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Click on the link to go back. <b>Note</b>: fade is default.</p>
        <a href="#pageone">Go to Page One</a>
      </div>

      <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK, after days of searching for an answer to what seems to be a elementary task, I have found the answer. Im have tested the solution and it is functioning as expected.                              <script type="text/JavaScript">

setTimeout("location.href = 'Your page url here';",5000);

</script>

Answer (score 0):

OK, after days of searching for an answer to what seems to be a elementary task, I have found the answer. Im have tested the solution and it is functioning as expected.

setTimeout("location.href = 'Your page url here';",5000);

I just viewed my posted answer, it appears the script open and close has been removed. The answer is a javascript, therefore the javascript open and close must be added.